# Is it bad practice if the executable depends on a library that is already used by another dependency?

Tags: build, shared-libraries, static-libraries

My current project has two libraries `libAAA` and `libBBB`.
The former, `libAAA`, contains basic math and mechanics for my project (e.g. the rules for chess). The latter, `libBBB`, depends on `libAAA` but adds GUI elements (e.g. how single figures are drawn).

The executable depends on both, `libAAA` and `libBBB`. E.g. `libBBB` is used to setup the chess game while `libBBB` is used to define how it looks (console, qt, gtk,...).

Is it OK to have such redundant dependencies or is it probably bad practice?

edit:
I ask that because I like how easy it is to decouple a GUI representation from the mechanics. E.g. if I would like to change the look or the toolkit, I could just add `libHHH`, make another executable and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine.

Let's look at some alternatives:

1. **Pull in all the code from `libAAA` into `libBBB`**:  This is alright if `libAAA` isn't intended to be used in other contexts, and their respective sizes allow this to be done in a practical manner. In many contexts though, e.g. if `libBBB` is much larger and `libAAA` is meant as a small reusable library for many projects independently of the UI framework used in `libBBB`, this won't work.
2. **Copy the code used by `libBBB` into it directly**: Please don't. This would mean two separate libraries that do a lot of the same things, two places to update in the future, more confusion for you in the future or for anyone else trying to understand it, etc.
3. **Bring the `libBBB` code into the application itself**: This is not always possible or practical, depending on your development stack and environment. Many applications may also need libraries that were programmed and compiled in a different language for performance or other reasons.

I'm probably missing a couple other alternative options, but keeping both dependencies despite the redundancy seems the best option to me.

As you stated in the edit, this also allows you to swap out `libBBB` for another UI library that also uses `libAAA`(or another lib if need be) without tearing down any of your core application code or invalidating any other code in your dependencies.